# Не скроллится экран

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть **Layout** файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linLayout_all_ivents_in_this_day"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_all_ivents_in_this_day"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

</LinearLayout>

Я добавляю его в другой **Layout** файл:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_dialog_new_ivent_new"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout_add_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

</LinearLayout>

Первый **layout** я добовляю "инфлэйтером" в

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout_add_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

Но экран не скроллится, даже если есть элементы ниже экрана? Очень прошу помочь и сказать, что я сделал не так. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А почему инфлэйтером, а не `<include>/<merge>`?

Comment: А что изменится? Я в коде добавляю календарь с liaerlayout чуток ниже календаря, в этот лэйаут я добавляю несколько объектов, но даже, если объекты ниже экрана, он не скроллится. Хотя заметил странность, если в первом файле в RelativeLayout1 изменить значение высоты с wrap_content на число, то экран начинает скроллится, но это меня не устраивает, календарь может изменяться в зависимости от количества дней, точные цифры подобрать нельзя, нужно более нормальное решение проблемы

Comment: Выставьте для `LinearLayout`'а, который вложенный в `ScrollView`, значение атрибута `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: Во-первых, ListView пустой, его можно и убрать, он висит там, пока что, просто так, и элементы в него не добавляются, но GridView должен быть обязательно, и он не должен скроллится.